# Why can't I craft scaffolding in Minecraft 1.14?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I want to use the scaffolding in 1.14 but the crafting recipe doesn't seem to be working. Is this a bug?

[image: In-Game Screenshot]

Comment: this is why the crafting book was made

Comment: probably because no one used sugar for creating structures

Answer (score 37, accepted):

As Dan Bron mentioned in the comments, you're trying to use **sugar canes**.

What you need to use is **bamboo**. They appear quite similar.

Here is the recipe you're looking for:

[image: scaffolding recipe]

Answer (score 6):

You need Bamboo, found in the jungle biome.

Comment: It would be nice if you have some picture to show him.